# How can I create a responsive Arrow-Pointer shape in CSS?

Tags: html, css, angular

I'm trying to build an EU Energy Efficiency Rating widget, which looks sth like this:
[image]

However, I'm struggling to create the arrow shape in a way that would be responsive to changes in height/width, plus I need a black border all around each arrow.
This is what I've come up with until now for each arrow:

```
span {
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: row;
  align-items: center;
  font-weight: 700;
  font-size: 1em;
  color: white;
  padding: 2%;
  height: 70%;
  background: #3b7634;
  width: 10%;
}

span::before {
  top: 0;
  background: linear-gradient(to right top, red 50%, transparent 50%);
}

span::after {
  bottom: 0;
  background: linear-gradient(to right bottom, red 50%, transparent 50%);
}
```

which looks like this:
[image]

Note how the tip is too "pointy" and a little rough. This is indeed responsive, but it's not pretty, nor is it possible to apply a border around the whole body + tip, bc the tip is created using linear-gradient.

So, is there any better way of doing it?
I'm using Angular btw.
Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You may also use [`clip-path`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/clip-path) to cut that arrow off.

> The `clip-path` CSS property creates a clipping region that sets what part of an element should be shown. Parts that are inside the region are shown, while those outside are hidden.

example

```css
/* cut an arrow shape on the right side */

span {
  clip-path: polygon( 0% 0%, calc(100% - 0.4em) 0%, 100% 50%, calc(100% - 0.4em) 100%, 0% 100%);
}


/* give it a shadow or a border ? */

div {
  filter: drop-shadow(2px 2px 2px);
}


/* styling : size and colors */

span {
  font-size: clamp(1em, 5vmax, 40px);
  padding-right: 0.5em;
  color: white;
  float: left;
  clear: left;
  margin: 0.1em;
}

span:nth-child(1) {
  background: #018133;
  padding-left: 2em;
}

span:nth-child(2) {
  background: #27B432;
  padding-left: 2.8em;
}

span:nth-child(3) {
  background: #88E213;
  padding-left: 3.6em;
}

span:nth-child(4) {
  background: #F0EF00;
  padding-left: 4.2em;
}

span:nth-child(5) {
  background: #FC9000;
  padding-left: 5em;
}

span:nth-child(6) {
  background: #FD0000;
  padding-left: 5.8em;
}

span:nth-child(7) {
  background: #FD001D;
  padding-left: 6.45em;
}
```

```html
<div>
  <span>A</span>
  <span>B</span>
  <span>C</span>
  <span>D</span>
  <span>E</span>
  <span>F</span>
  <span>G</span>
</div>
```

[Codepen demo](https://codepen.io/gc-nomade/pen/zYzPJyK)

Here is an online tool to help you create your first shapes (many examples ready to copy/paste) https://bennettfeely.com/clippy/

Comment: After testing out the different solutions, yours turned out to be the best, and I have to give you credit for that, thanks a bunch!

Comment: Great ! solution.. saved my weekend..my daughter will thank you :-) as I will play with her now :-D

Answer (score 2):

You would want to use a triangle rather than a linear-gradient. For example:

https://codepen.io/seanstopnik/pen/072a65f5fa4a4da25e46506f7c19fb3d

```css
* {
  box-sizing: border-box;
}

.arrow {
  position: relative;
  width: 20%;
  height: 22px;
  color: #fff;
  text-align: right;
  background-color: red;
  padding: 2px 10px;
}

.arrow--right:before {
  position: absolute;
  width: 0;
  height: 0;
  content: "";
  border-width: 11px;
  border-style: solid;
  border-color: transparent;
  border-left-color: red;
  top: 0;
  right: -22px;
}
```

```html
<div class="arrow arrow--right">A</div>
```

Comment: While this is indeed a neat solution, it doesn't completely address the issue of responsiveness. I need the height/thickness of the arrow to be resp. too.

Comment: @sean stopnik: Great work. Is it possible to have rounded corner triangle. Just asking :)

Answer (score 1):

This is the best I can come up with using `calc` and 1px images. I'd imagine this technique works with square `<svg>`s as well.

The downsides of this is:

- I can't think of a way to perfectly calculate the bar width to minus the protruding arrow tip.
- Not purely CSS. But this works great when you're already using a component framework.

#### The tip

I'm not sure if there's a way to make a dynamic square with height at 100%. The reverse is absolutely possible though. https://spin.atomicobject.com/2015/07/14/css-responsive-square/

The solution here is to use a square image to exploit the browser's ability to maintain image aspect ratios.

This is a 1px transparent PNG image I found online. We should also be aware that we can't use `::before` or `::after` with images.

#### The border

CSS can't do borders with odd shapes, but we can hack it. Here I'm using `box-shadow`. But you can also use actual `border`. Sometimes, you can use 2 different rectangles for borders as well.

The solution here is to separate the background color and the borders at different levels, because around the bend, the horizontal border actually needs to overlap into the tilted square. (Or vice versa, the border of the tilted square needs to overlap the horizontal borders.)

---

But overall, I think this looks most like the energy efficiency arrow.

```css
* { box-sizing: border-box; }

.efficiency {
  border: 1px solid black;
  /* Remove the following rules to support older browsers. */
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: column;
  gap: 3px;
}

.bar {
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: row;
  align-items: center;
  font-weight: 700;
  font-size: 1em;
  color: white;
  flex: 1;
  background: #3b7634;
  position: relative;
  z-index: 0;
  /*
  If you want to support older browsers:
  height: calc(100% / 7 - 3px);
  margin-bottom: 3px;
  */
}

.bar > .text {
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: row;
  align-items: center;
  height: 100%;
  width: 100%;
  border: 2px solid black;
  border-right: none;
  z-index: 1;
}

.a { width: 20%; background-color: #00A851 }
.b { width: 30%; background-color: #4FB947 }
.c { width: 40%; background-color: #C1D82D }
.d { width: 50%; background-color: #FEF200 }
.e { width: 60%; background-color: #FCBA0B }
.f { width: 70%; background-color: #F3711A }
.g { width: 80%; background-color: #EE141F }

.arrow {
  height: calc(100% / 1.41421356237); /* square root 2 */
  transform: translateX(-50%) rotate(45deg);
  position: absolute;
  left: 100%;
  user-select: none;
  background-color: inherit;
  box-shadow: inset -2px 2px black;
}
```

```html
<h1>These look great</h1>

<div class="efficiency" style="width: 400px; height: 300px">
  <div class="bar a"><img class="arrow" src="data:image/png;base64,iVBORw0KGgoAAAANSUhEUgAAAAEAAAABCAQAAAC1HAwCAAAAC0lEQVR42mNkYAAAAAYAAjCB0C8AAAAASUVORK5CYII="><div class="text">A</div></div>
  <div class="bar b"><img class="arrow" src="data:image/png;base64,iVBORw0KGgoAAAANSUhEUgAAAAEAAAABCAQAAAC1HAwCAAAAC0lEQVR42mNkYAAAAAYAAjCB0C8AAAAASUVORK5CYII="><div class="text">B</div></div>
  <div class="bar c"><img class="arrow" src="data:image/png;base64,iVBORw0KGgoAAAANSUhEUgAAAAEAAAABCAQAAAC1HAwCAAAAC0lEQVR42mNkYAAAAAYAAjCB0C8AAAAASUVORK5CYII="><div class="text">C</div></div>
  <div class="bar d"><img class="arrow" src="data:image/png;base64,iVBORw0KGgoAAAANSUhEUgAAAAEAAAABCAQAAAC1HAwCAAAAC0lEQVR42mNkYAAAAAYAAjCB0C8AAAAASUVORK5CYII="><div class="text">D</div></div>
  <div class="bar e"><img class="arrow" src="data:image/png;base64,iVBORw0KGgoAAAANSUhEUgAAAAEAAAABCAQAAAC1HAwCAAAAC0lEQVR42mNkYAAAAAYAAjCB0C8AAAAASUVORK5CYII="><div class="text">E</div></div>
  <div class="bar f"><img class="arrow" src="data:image/png;base64,iVBORw0KGgoAAAANSUhEUgAAAAEAAAABCAQAAAC1HAwCAAAAC0lEQVR42mNkYAAAAAYAAjCB0C8AAAAASUVORK5CYII="><div class="text">F</div></div>
  <div class="bar g"><img class="arrow" src="data:image/png;base64,iVBORw0KGgoAAAANSUhEUgAAAAEAAAABCAQAAAC1HAwCAAAAC0lEQVR42mNkYAAAAAYAAjCB0C8AAAAASUVORK5CYII="><div class="text">G</div></div>
</div>

<div class="efficiency" style="width: 300px; height: 400px">
  <div class="bar a"><img class="arrow" src="data:image/png;base64,iVBORw0KGgoAAAANSUhEUgAAAAEAAAABCAQAAAC1HAwCAAAAC0lEQVR42mNkYAAAAAYAAjCB0C8AAAAASUVORK5CYII="><div class="text">A</div></div>
  <div class="bar b"><img class="arrow" src="data:image/png;base64,iVBORw0KGgoAAAANSUhEUgAAAAEAAAABCAQAAAC1HAwCAAAAC0lEQVR42mNkYAAAAAYAAjCB0C8AAAAASUVORK5CYII="><div class="text">B</div></div>
  <div class="bar c"><img class="arrow" src="data:image/png;base64,iVBORw0KGgoAAAANSUhEUgAAAAEAAAABCAQAAAC1HAwCAAAAC0lEQVR42mNkYAAAAAYAAjCB0C8AAAAASUVORK5CYII="><div class="text">C</div></div>
  <div class="bar d"><img class="arrow" src="data:image/png;base64,iVBORw0KGgoAAAANSUhEUgAAAAEAAAABCAQAAAC1HAwCAAAAC0lEQVR42mNkYAAAAAYAAjCB0C8AAAAASUVORK5CYII="><div class="text">D</div></div>
  <div class="bar e"><img class="arrow" src="data:image/png;base64,iVBORw0KGgoAAAANSUhEUgAAAAEAAAABCAQAAAC1HAwCAAAAC0lEQVR42mNkYAAAAAYAAjCB0C8AAAAASUVORK5CYII="><div class="text">E</div></div>
  <div class="bar f"><img class="arrow" src="data:image/png;base64,iVBORw0KGgoAAAANSUhEUgAAAAEAAAABCAQAAAC1HAwCAAAAC0lEQVR42mNkYAAAAAYAAjCB0C8AAAAASUVORK5CYII="><div class="text">F</div></div>
  <div class="bar g"><img class="arrow" src="data:image/png;base64,iVBORw0KGgoAAAANSUhEUgAAAAEAAAABCAQAAAC1HAwCAAAAC0lEQVR42mNkYAAAAAYAAjCB0C8AAAAASUVORK5CYII="><div class="text">G</div></div>
</div>

<h1>Just don't go extreme</h1>

<div class="efficiency" style="width: 100px; height: 400px">
  <div class="bar a"><img class="arrow" src="data:image/png;base64,iVBORw0KGgoAAAANSUhEUgAAAAEAAAABCAQAAAC1HAwCAAAAC0lEQVR42mNkYAAAAAYAAjCB0C8AAAAASUVORK5CYII="><div class="text">A</div></div>
  <div class="bar b"><img class="arrow" src="data:image/png;base64,iVBORw0KGgoAAAANSUhEUgAAAAEAAAABCAQAAAC1HAwCAAAAC0lEQVR42mNkYAAAAAYAAjCB0C8AAAAASUVORK5CYII="><div class="text">B</div></div>
  <div class="bar c"><img class="arrow" src="data:image/png;base64,iVBORw0KGgoAAAANSUhEUgAAAAEAAAABCAQAAAC1HAwCAAAAC0lEQVR42mNkYAAAAAYAAjCB0C8AAAAASUVORK5CYII="><div class="text">C</div></div>
  <div class="bar d"><img class="arrow" src="data:image/png;base64,iVBORw0KGgoAAAANSUhEUgAAAAEAAAABCAQAAAC1HAwCAAAAC0lEQVR42mNkYAAAAAYAAjCB0C8AAAAASUVORK5CYII="><div class="text">D</div></div>
  <div class="bar e"><img class="arrow" src="data:image/png;base64,iVBORw0KGgoAAAANSUhEUgAAAAEAAAABCAQAAAC1HAwCAAAAC0lEQVR42mNkYAAAAAYAAjCB0C8AAAAASUVORK5CYII="><div class="text">E</div></div>
  <div class="bar f"><img class="arrow" src="data:image/png;base64,iVBORw0KGgoAAAANSUhEUgAAAAEAAAABCAQAAAC1HAwCAAAAC0lEQVR42mNkYAAAAAYAAjCB0C8AAAAASUVORK5CYII="><div class="text">F</div></div>
  <div class="bar g"><img class="arrow" src="data:image/png;base64,iVBORw0KGgoAAAANSUhEUgAAAAEAAAABCAQAAAC1HAwCAAAAC0lEQVR42mNkYAAAAAYAAjCB0C8AAAAASUVORK5CYII="><div class="text">G</div></div>
</div>
```

[image]

Comment: I stand baffled at the sheer beauty of your answer. Thanks a million man.

Comment: @Abdul-QaderHaddad no problem. These are indeed some neat CSS tricks which are used at times like these. Hope you got to learn something from this.

Comment: @Abdul-QaderHaddad I updated my answer to better explain code. See if you find it useful.