# Wrap large text in arrow shape div block

Tags: html, css, bootstrap-4

How can I wrap large text in arrow and also change arrow size to wrap large text with changing screen size?
Please refer to code below  ,it creates arrow but if I increase text then arrow becomes long but I want a shorter one which wraps text in two lines and changes shape based on screen size.

```css
.blockHead:after {
  color: #4D81BF;
  border-left: 20px solid;
  border-top: 20px solid transparent;
  border-bottom: 20px solid transparent;
  display: inline-block;
  content: '';
  position: absolute;
  right: -20px;
  top: 0;
}
.blockHead {
  background-color: #4D81BF;
  /*width: 150px; */
  height: 40px;
  line-height: 40px;
  display: inline-block;
  position: relative;
}
.blocktext {
  color: white;
  font-weight: bold;
  padding-left: 10px;
  font-family: Arial;
  font-size: 11;
}
```

```html
<div class="blockHead"><span class="blocktext">ABC Team</span>
</div>
```

Comment: You'd have to remove the fixed height and limit the width to start with.

Comment: Oh and then you'd have to futz with a different method of creating the point since the border method probably won't work,

Comment: Have you investigated clip path?

Comment: A Haworth clip path worked for me.

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/69195570/how-can-i-create-a-responsive-arrow-pointer-shape-in-css  this links worked for me.